# Can't install flask-mysql fedora

Tags: python, mysql, flask, pip, fedora

I'm trying to install `flask-mysql` with pip on fedora 22, but I get this error:

```
Collecting flask-mysql
  Using cached Flask_MySQL-1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask-mysql)
Collecting MySQL-python (from flask-mysql)
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-IH7lNv/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-IH7lNv/MySQL-python
```

I searched a lot, but all the solutions were for debian based OS's which needed to download `libmysqlclient-dev` but there is no such package in fedora

Comment: Do you have the MySQL client installed?

Comment: @dirn yes of course .